# Selenium unable to locate element even if this element exists

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click on the See Story button where (you need to be logged in): https://www.instagram.com/stories/inoxtag/

Button HTML (with French text):

```
<button class="_acan _acap _acau _acav" type="button">Voir story</button>
```

I'm using Selenium and Python.

My code is:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/div[1]/div/section/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/button").click()
```

And it leads me to this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/div[1]/div/section/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/button"}
```

I'm using xpath because the button class seems to be obfuscated, so I prefer to do it by xpath.
I know my xpath is correct because if I do F12 on the webpage, then paste my xpath I have my button selected.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So I debugged your problem. When you open (driver.get(...)) the link, have you taken into account all the "Allow essential and optional cookies", and then logging in into your account?

If you have debugged this in incognito mode and kept the window open, incognito would have stored your data and so wouldn't ask you for your details again.

But if you debug the script and just put a break point on the line

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/div[1]/div/section/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/button").click()`

Then you proceed to fill your data until it routes you to the page you showed and then you try to execute the code that clicks the button you wouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this was related to allowing cookies! Have a great day